# Change size of navigationIcon in MaterialToolbar

Tags: android, kotlin, resize, icons, material-design

I am trying to put a profile image in navigationIcon, but any photos are too big for the ToolBar.
How can I resize navigatioIcon or photos using Kotlin? Help pls

```
   <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:title="Ticketon"
        app:navigationIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        app:menu="@menu/toolbar_menu"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
        />
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

topAppBar.setNavigationIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you should be able to do it without any code. That icon is set on an `ImageButton` that has its `scaleType` set to `center` by default. We should be able to change that with a `style`, but since you're already using one on the `<Toolbar>`, we'll set the `toolbarNavigationButtonStyle` theme attribute instead, so it doesn't interfere with `Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary`, without having to mess with modifying that. This should work, but I can't test it right this minute: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y7snBCiwSGWtg6Z4JGk5JtTSOZ_d4Qgn/view?usp=drivesdk.

Comment: I've edited that example with a couple of other attribute adjustments that I'd not thought of before testing, but the original idea does indeed work, if this is what you're going for: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jx7P4.png.

Comment: @MikeM. thank you so much, it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest this approach:

```
class CustomMaterialToolbar(ctx: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : MaterialToolbar(ctx, attrs) {

override fun setNavigationIcon(drawable: Drawable?) {
    super.setNavigationIcon(drawable)
    val iconSize = (ICON_SIZE_DP * (resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi / 160f)).roundToInt()
    val button = getNavigationIconButton(this)!!
    val iconLayoutParams = button.layoutParams
    iconLayoutParams.width = iconSize
    iconLayoutParams.height = iconSize

    button.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER

    button.layoutParams = iconLayoutParams
}

private fun getNavigationIconButton(toolbar: Toolbar): ImageButton? {
    val navigationIcon = toolbar.navigationIcon ?: return null
    for (i in 0 until toolbar.childCount) {
        val child = toolbar.getChildAt(i)
        if (child is ImageButton) {
            if (child.drawable === navigationIcon) {
                return child
            }
        }
    }
    return null
}

companion object {
    const val ICON_SIZE_DP = 24
}
```

}